# How to pass dynamic amount of optional parameters to Python function

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a function that is being used with 2 optional parameters *offset* and *limit*:

```
query = db.engine.execute(sql, offset=pagination.offset, limit=pagination.limit)
```

Is there a way I can pass it a list of dynamic parameters? Something like this:

```
db.engine.execute(sql, param_obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build the optional parameters as a `dict` and pass it to the function

```
param_obj = dict(offset=pagination.offset, limit=pagination.limit)
db.engine.execute(sql, **param_obj)
```

Or if you really want to pass the optional paraemters as list, you can, but care should be taken to ensure the order of parameters being passed

```
param_obj = [pagination.offset, pagination.limit]
db.engine.execute(sql, *param_obj)
```